# How to add link to marker using gmaps4rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I would like to add a marker with link in marker, so, when i click that marker, i will redirect to another page

Is anybody know to do it?

Thanks

---

I already added my code like this :

In controller:

```
@json = @businesses.results.to_gmaps4rails do |object|
  "\"link\": \"#{root_url}\""
end
```

In view :

```
  <%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
  <% content_for :scripts do %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function redirect_to(url) {
        window.location = url;
      };
      Gmaps4Rails.callback = function() {
        function say_yo(arg) { return function(){alert('yo '+ arg + '!' );};};
        for (var i = 0; i <  Gmaps4Rails.markers.length; ++i) {
          google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps4Rails.markers[i].google_object, 'click', redirect_to(Gmaps4Rails.markers[i].link));
        }
      }
    </script>
  <% end %>
```

Is it any wrong? because there just an info window that show after i clicked the marker(Not redirect to any page)

[image]

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a forum. Questions are questions, answers are answers. To add more info to your question, you're supposed to edit the question. Check out the [FAQ].

Answer (score 2):

First include the link inside the json:

```
Model.all.to_gmaps4rails do |object|
  "\"link\": \"your link as string\""
end
```

Then add the extra listeners in your view (beware to include this AFTER your call to the gmaps method):

```
<%= gmaps(whatever you need here) %>

<% content_for :scripts do %>
<script type="text/javascript">
function redirect_to(url) {
  window.location = url;
};
Gmaps4Rails.callback = function() { 
  function say_yo(arg) { return function(){alert('yo '+ arg + '!' );};};
    for (var i = 0; i <  Gmaps4Rails.markers.length; ++i) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(Gmaps4Rails.markers[i].google_object, 'click', redirect_to(Gmaps4Rails.markers[i].link));
    }
}
</script>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi apneadiving, thx for ur answer. But i get error message _Gmaps4Rails is not defined_ in code partGmaps4Rails.callback = function() { .Why is it happen?

Comment: Because you have to write this function after you call gmaps4rails, and in a "content_for :scripts".

Comment: could you please answer my new question after i edit the question? because link still can't redirect to other page

Comment: I try to debug @json result and there are no link data. Below is result :{\n\"description\": \"A-ABC Locksmith <br/> 7063 W Belmont Ave\", \"title\": \"\", \"sidebar\": \"\",\n\"longitude\": \"-87.8037\", \"latitude\": \"41.938\", \"picture\": \"\", \"width\": \"\", \"height\": \"\"\n}

Comment: I already updated my gem version to 0.10.2, but when i add content_for :script, page always redirect to root path while my url are /list

Comment: Update your question with the resulting html. I can't debug otherwise

Comment: - there are no wrong redirect to again, but there just an infowindow when i click marker - I also debug @json data and link already availabled..I attached my view when i click the marker